# Sales without associated accounts with a Left Join?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I thought I understood how to do this, but I might be missing something. Would this not work?

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM Sale A
LEFT JOIN Account B on A.Sale_id= B.Sale_id
WHERE account_id IS NULL
```

[image: Tables involved]

Comment: Provided `account_id` is not nullable looks ok to me. It should find exactly sales without an account.

Comment: `FROM Sale_id`? What is the name of the table?

Comment: Bad habbits to kick: [using-table-aliases-like-a-b-c-or-t1-t2-t3](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-table-aliases-like-a-b-c-or-t1-t2-t3)

Comment: @forpas - edited (should be "Sale")

Comment: `WHERE NOT EXISTS` might be more performant, it's certainly more obvious

Answer (score 0):

You can do this in one of the many ways. For Instance

**Use `NOT IN` Operator**

```
Select 
     * 
from Sale 
where 
    Sale_id NOT IN (SELECT DISTINCT(Sale_id) FROM Account)
```

Subquery will return the sale ids which has records in Account Table. NOT IN operator returns all other records from Sale Table

**Use `LEFT JOIN`**

```
Select 
   s.*
from Sale s left join Account a on s.Sale_id=a.Sale_id
where a.Sale_id is null
```